# Finding particular words in string

Tags: php, regex, strpos

I want to search the string which contains `Rathi 25mm` but I don't want to use the complete word to search .How can i do the search using specific words?

*`Rathi Stelmax 500 25 mm in stripos`*

```
   <?php
    $title='Rathi Stelmax 500 25 mm';

    if (stripos(strtolower($title), 'Rathi  25 mm') !== false)
    { 
      echo 'true';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: try to use regular expression

Comment: How do you decide which words to search for?

Comment: by using preg_match()@rahul?

Comment: this is static in this case@chris85

Comment: anything in between is allowed @chris85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Using your current approach you can run multiple `stripos`s in the conditional to confirm each word is there:

```
$title='Rathi Stelmax 500 25 mm';
if (stripos(strtolower($title), 'Rathi') !== false && stripos(strtolower($title),  '25 mm'))
    { echo 'true';
    }
```

Demo: https://eval.in/628147

You also could use a regex such as:

```
/Rathi.*25 mm/
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/628148
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cZ6bL1/1

PHP Usage:

```
$title='Rathi Stelmax 500 25 mm';
if (preg_match('/Rathi.*25 mm/', $title)) { 
     echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script

```
 $title="Rathi Stelmax 500 25 mm";
if(preg_match("/(Rathi|25|mm)/i", $title)){
  //one of these string found
}
```

Comment: This will allow just `Rathi`, `25`, or `mm` but never all 3.

Comment: this will search for either rathi or either 25mm not both @user853278

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use preg_match_all.

Thats a REGEX function.
Here is a small example:

```
$input_lines = 'Hello i am 250 years old from Mars'
preg_match_all("/(\d+)|(Mars)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

$output_array would hold an array with the following data:

```
0   =>  array(2
    0   =>  250
    1   =>  Mars
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reluctant to use regexp, you can split your search string in words, and check that each of them is contained in the string :

```
$title = 'Rathi Stelmax 500 25 mm';
$lookFor = 'Rathi 25 mm';

$counter = 0;
$searchElements = explode(' ', $lookFor);
foreach($searchElements as $search){
    if(strpos($title, $search) !== false){
        $counter++;
    }
}

if(count($searchElements) == $counter){
    echo 'found everything';
}
else{
    echo 'found ' . $counter . ' element(s)';
}
```

It's probably less efficient than a regexp, but also probably easier to grasp.